# Extract a substring from a webpage after it loads

Tags: arrays, pandas, selenium, substring

This is the **page** I'm trying to extract: https://rocketreach.co/goldman-sachs-email-format_b5c61cb4f42e0c49

This is the substring I'm trying to extract from the page and put in a list or array.: [image]
**Desired output for this:** [first.last@gs.com]
Note that there's a bit of a delay to load the page so it outputs some latin words, that's why I have the webdriverwait function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import urllib.request
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
   import pandas as pd
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def search_on_google(key_word, driver):
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

searchboard = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
searchboard.send_keys(key_word + " Rocketreach.co")
searchboard.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
searchboard.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.find_element_by_tag_name("cite").click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1][not(contains(text(), 'Lorem ipsum...'))]")))
table_id = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for td in tds:
        one_urls.append(tds[0].text)
        one_urls.append(tds[1].text)
        break
print(one_urls)
```

**Current output:**  ["first '.' last", 'jane.doe@gs.com'].
**Desired output:**  [first.last@gs.com]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using selenium instead of just using beautifulsoup with the url you want to parse? Even if you want to search multiple sites, you can always just create a list of urls for bs4.

Comment: I'm very new to this. No particular reason. Could you show me how to do it the way you say? Basically the input is an excel sheet with the first column as company name. And that's the "keyword" that I'm passing to my search_on_google and clicking on the first link. I'm using this Rocketreach site to understand the top-most email format of the company.  Desired output: [first.last@gs.com]

Comment: @BenPap Sorry I forgot to tag you

Comment: Remove your first 2 items from array, or, use this locator: //div[@class='headline-summary']//b[2]  then make a substring to get onlu first.last@gs.com